# how to export signing identity from Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, provisioning-profile

In Xcode 6, I clicked: Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts

I've shoosen my account and then clicked on "settings wheel in the bottom left corner and then : export accounts...

I've set name and password for the exported account and clicked save and I've got this message:

[image]

Have you an idea how can export account to import it on another mac?

Comment: is the account present in the keychain? If yes, try exporting the certificate from the keychain

Comment: if I search for my account in a keychain there are 4 positions. Two of them are type of "internet passwords" (daw2.apple.com and idmsa.apple.com) and two of them are www passwords named: idmsa.apple.com and itunesconnect.apple.com). I can't export it from keychain - Export option is greyed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signing identity is a private key in the keychain on the Mac that made the certificate request to Apple.  Determining which is the correct private key may take trial and error if the names and descriptions do not help.

Export the private key from /Applications/Utilities/"Keychain Access".

Import that private key to "Keychain Access" on the other Mac you want authorized to sign the app.

After verifying the private key works on the destination Mac, you may want to delete the private key from the original Mac for security.

Comment: It makes sense. I will test it in the evening and let you know if that works. I don't want to delete the private key from original mac. Both are mine so I would like to sign  apps from both.